# How to map multiple HTTP Verbs to the same path in HTTP4K

Tags: rest, kotlin, http4k

I have a route similar to the one below working fine in HTTP4K. However it is annoying having to repeat the calls to **"/" bind**. I have looked for a simpler way to express the DSL but nothing else seems to work. Is there any way to achieve this?

```
routes(
    "/things" bind routes(
        "/" bind Method.GET to allThings,
        "/{id:.*}" bind routes (
            "/" bind Method.GET to singleThing,
            "/" bind Method.DELETE to deleteThing,
            "/" bind Method.PUT to addOrUpdateThing
        )
    )
).asServer(Netty(8080))
    .start()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a convenience function of the same name which accepts a vararg of `Pair<Method, HttpHandler>`, you should be able to drop the leading `"/" bind` as follows:

```
routes(
    "/things" bind routes(
        "/" bind Method.GET to allThings,
        "/{id:.*}" bind routes(
            Method.GET to singleThing,
            Method.DELETE to deleteThing,
            Method.PUT to addOrUpdateThing
        )
    )
).asServer(Netty(8080))
    .start()
```